# In American football, which team is on offense first?

Tags: rules, american-football

Is it guaranteed to be the home team or the away team, or is it decided randomly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Captains from both teams meet with the referee before the game and the visiting team calls the toss. The winner, chooses to either kick the ball/receive the kickoff or an end to defend at the start of the game.

Comment: To add to this answer, this is found in the NFL rules under "[Coin Toss](http://www.nfl.com/rulebook/cointoss)."